# How can I show the user name of the other user?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a app and in that a chat function were chat working correctly and user name correctly diplayed. But now im trying to add a appBar and im getting an error. What I want is trying to build the name of the other user and not mine . So an example: I chat with my friend and in the app bar I wanna see his name so I know with how Im chatting . but how do I do that?. Heres how my chat app locks at the moment.
So heres how I use the username in chat bubble and it works fine :

```
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubble(this.message, this.isMe, this.username, {this.key});

  final Key key;
  final String message;
  final bool isMe;
  String username;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment:
            isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: isMe ? Colors.grey[300] : Colors.black,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                    bottomLeft:
                        !isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(12),
                    bottomRight:
                        isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(12),
                  )),
              width: 140,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 16),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment:
                      isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      username,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: isMe
                              ? Colors.black
                              : Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      message,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: isMe
                              ? Colors.black
                              : Colors.white),
                      textAlign: isMe ? TextAlign.end : TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                  ]))
        ]);
  }
}
```

It displayed the correct username and the correct user message .

And heres how I wanna use it in the app bar:

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  CustomAppBar({this.key, this.username,this.isMe} ) : super(key: key);

  final Key key;
  final bool isMe;
  final String username;
  //String username;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Build you AppBar widget here
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black,),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 2,),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/5.jpg'),
                  maxRadius: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 12,),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        username, style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
                      SizedBox(height: 6,),
                      Text("Online", style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade600, fontSize: 13),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.black54,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(56);
}
```

And heres I wanna displayed it :

```
class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  static const route = '/messages';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:CustomAppBar()
      ,
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Messages()),
          NewMessage(),
        ],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass the `username` as `String` (and other parameters) in the `CustomAppBar` constructor like this:

```dart
class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  static const route = '/messages';

  final String username;
  
  ChatScreen({@required this.username});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
          username: username, // This is dynamic..
          isMe: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Messages()),
          NewMessage(),
        ],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You need to get first the `username` of the other user and then you can create your `ChatScreen`:

```dart
//...some code...
String username = getUsername(); // This is your method to get the username

Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatScreen(username: username)));
```

Comment: Yes I was also trying this but it shows now username and not the real username of user .Like in Messagebubble class

Comment: You need to get first the username of the other user and then you pass it!

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope that's more clear

Comment: Im getting already the username im using it already as I sad in the chat bubble please check my code

Comment: Also this will not work because I wanna get an page that shows all chat from user .And then on pressed user will get to chat screen and on the page before where all chats all listed I want screen user name and also user message so I already need it there ,how do this work like your sad with first getting username .im wrong ? or I just dont understand how you mean it ?

Comment: You are getting the username in the `Messages`, but you need it also in your `CustomAppBar` of the `ChatScreen`!

Comment: Ahhh now I understand what you mean so I can't just use it everywhere . But how do I get the user name again ,can you maybe give me some code help?

Comment: I have given you all the tools you need to develop the solution. Before navigating to `ChatScreen` you need to retrieve the recipient's username from Firebase. In the "chat" document (or as you called it) you can enter the necessary metadata such as 'sender', 'recipient' and so on ... In this way you can retrieve the username and then access the ChatScreen

Comment: I do not really understand how do you mean that with ''ou can enter the necessary metadata such as 'sender', 'recipient''but you answered my first question so I mark this answer as correct I will open a new question maybe anyone can explain better .Thanks have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when you are calling CustomAppBar() you are not passing any info/strings to it, that's causing your null error regarding a null string.

It should be i.e CustomAppBar (userName).

Comment: Where you got the userName from? I mean where do I use it ?